# Don't Play iOS Push Notification Sound While the app is in active/foreground

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am getting Push Notification while the application is in foreground. When the application is in foreground state, I don't want **it** to play any sound. How I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass `.sound` into the callback for `userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter